# Why function is undefined in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, arrow-functions

Could you help me and say what is wrong with this simple web server?
Why `validateWebhook` is `undefined` right after declaring and in callback in this `const result = validateWebhook(req.body);` line? **And how to fix this?**

Looks like something wrong and I'm missing something, but can't understand what's wrong.

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const Ajv = require('ajv');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

/* Create validateWebHook function */ 
/* This function validates input JSON supplied to webhook */
const validateWebhook = ((filePath) => {
    fs.promises.readFile(filePath, {options: 'utf8'})
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(`Validation schema [${filePath}]:`);
        console.log(`${data}`);

        const ajv = new Ajv();
        const result = ajv.compile(data);
        console.log(`Type is ${typeof result}`);
        return result;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Error loading json schema [${filePath}]`);
        console.log(`Details: [${error}]`);
    }); 
})('./schemas/waboxapp.json');
console.log(`Type is ${typeof validateWebhook}`);

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Input JSON: ${req.body}`);
    console.log(`Type is ${typeof validateWebhook}`);
    const result = validateWebhook(req.body);
    console.log(`Validation result: ${result}`);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

This is JSON schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "http://lookin.im/schemas/input/waboxapp.json",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "event":   { "type": "string" },
        "token":   { "type": "string" },
        "uid":     { "type": "string" },
        "contact": { "$ref": "#/definitions/contact" },
        "message": { "$ref": "#/definitions/message" }
    },
    "required": [ "event", "token", "uid", "contact", "message" ],
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "definitions": {
        "contact": {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
            "$id": "http://lookin.im/schemas/input/contact.json",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "uid":  { "type": "string" },
                "name": { "type": "string" },
                "type": { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": [ "uid", "name", "type" ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "message": {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
            "$id": "http://lookin.im/schemas/input/message.json",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "dtm":  { "type": "string" },
                "uid":  { "type": "string" },
                "cuid": { "type": "string" },
                "dir":  { "type": "string" },
                "type": { "type": "string" },
                "ack":  { "type": "string" },
                "body": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "text": { "type": "string" }
                    },
                    "required": [ "text" ],
                    "additionalProperties": false
                }
            },
            "required": [ "dtm", "uid", "cuid", "dir", "type", "ack", "body" ],
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    }
}
```

And my HTTP request I'm sending to express js:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 5d96ffe2-8f5f-477c-bc82-cd53147208c1

event=message&token=a09c8f3&uid=1&contact%5Buid%5D=1&contact%5Bname%5D=Name&contact%5Btype%5D=user&message%5Bdtm%5D=1&message%5Buid%5D=1&message%5Bcuid%5D=&message%5Bdir%5D=i&message%5Btype%5D=chat&message%5Bbody%5D%5Btext%5D=Test&message%5Back%5D=3
```

It's how to send this request with curl utility:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:3000/ \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: c319bdbe-16a9-42ab-a96b-2262e0c1fd81' \
  -d 'event=message&token=a09c8f3&uid=1&contact%5Buid%5D=1&contact%5Bname%5D=Name&contact%5Btype%5D=user&message%5Bdtm%5D=1&message%5Buid%5D=1&message%5Bcuid%5D=&message%5Bdir%5D=i&message%5Btype%5D=chat&message%5Bbody%5D%5Btext%5D=Test&message%5Back%5D=3'
```

**Note:** I'm using latest versions of dependencies.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Test",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.5.2",
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  }
}
```

Node version is **v10.5.0**.

Comment: It's `undefined` because the code in that function doesn't return anything. The `return` inside the `.then()` callback won't do anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scooping out the inner parts of your code to highlight the problem, here's what you've written:

```
const validateWebhook = ((filePath) => {
  // Stuff, with no return statement 
})('./schemas/waboxapp.json');
```

This is an immediately invoked function expression. It will immediately call the `(filepath) => {}` function, passing in './schemas/waboxapp.json', and whatever you return will then be assigned to validateWebhook. But you don't return anything, so it gets set to undefined.

Comment: This is the correct answer. What you probably intended to write is a function that takes a string and returns a function. Immediately invoked, the type of validateWebHook would be a function. You have written a function from string to void. Immediately invoked, it returns undefined.

Comment: But how to fix this? I need to return function, but as I've understood `return result` in then is evaluated to new promise, which inherently discarded. How to  return value from promise (and that value is function)?

Comment: If you want to interact with the result of a promise, use its `.then` method. You pass a function into `.then`, and that function will be run once the promise resolves.

Comment: But that way Promise infects code so everything should be inside `.then` and it will deep nested already.

Comment: Yes, writing asynchronous code requires you to modify the way you write things. But with regard to nesting, one of the main benefits of promises it that they let you **avoid** nesting. You can pass the promise object wherever it's needed, and call `.then` wherever makes the most sense. When you call `.then`, a new promise is returned, so rather than having to nest things inside eachother you can chain them. You call `.then`, which creates a new promise, then call `.then` on that promise, which creates a new one, etc.